# how I can match date with format like 01-Nov-2019 in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please can any one tell me how I can match my date with format like eg.01-Nov-2019

Note : 01    => can match 01 to 31 , Nov   => can match Jan to Dec and  2019  => can match valid 4 digit year

And same for time format like 08:12

I am only using HTML and javascript

Comment: Please, show us what you tried so far, so we can help you better

Comment: Seems like a simple regular expression should be able to do it.

Comment: Search for `[javascript] regular expression date` and you'll find many examples of matching different date formats. Even if you can't find your exact format, you should be able to generalize.

Comment: Actually I have taken text input field.And when user enter like 01-Nov-2019 manually then I want error alert on click of button

Comment: It's a bit unclear as to what exactly you're after. It seems counterintuitive for you to alert after someone manually enters a date in a format other than what you want (by today's tandards). If you want it in a particular format, then you should restrict options to direct your users in the right direction; this is why date inputs typically have pop-up calendars.

Answer (score 1):

Non-regex

```
var date = new Date();
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var dateString;

date.setDate(date.getDate());

dateString = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-'  + months[date.getMonth()]+ '-' + date.getFullYear();
time = ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':'  + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2)  + (date.getHours()>12?"PM":"AM");
console.log(time+" -> "+dateString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use w3schools? They have good tutorials.

[Javascript Dates](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp)